# Can't get index.html to show with Express in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to run my first express app, but can't seem to get my webpage to show.  I have the following code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("files/config.json"));  
var host = config.host;
var port = config.port;
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(request, response){
    response.send("hello!");
});

app.listen(port, host);
console.log("Listening on port" + port);
```

Here is my directory tree

```
nodejs/
    js/
        javascript.js
    public/
        index.html
```

I know the server is running because I get my `"Hello!"` response in the browser when I run `127.0.0.01:1337`

But when I try and type the webpage `1227.0.0.1:1337/index.html`, I get `Cannot GET /index.html` displayed in the browser

So I'm guessing it's something wrong with the `name` value in my `get` method, but can't figure out what it is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your app will only route page requests that are set up at the time of your `app.use(app.router)` call.  So reorder your `app.use` calls to be one of the following:

## Express 3

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(app.router);
```

[`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) is the directory that the executing script resides in, so because that lives in the `js` directory that's a peer to `public` your code would need to be:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../public"));
app.use(app.router);
```

## Express 4

Express 4 [removes the need to manually do `app.use(app.router)`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#approuter). With Express 4 you just need:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../public"));`

Comment: Express 4 example worked for me. `app.use(app.router);` gives an error that it is deprecated

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, although Express.js website guide won't show it any different. My structure is slightly different:
myapp/
app.js
index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue .... after a lot of trouble I find that if you run two workspaces or project at t time then it will create this scenario. so you might open only a workspace at a time and not just file ... open the hole folder then run the specific file.make the following change in your VS code setting.

> setup the settings

For 64bit system.

```
{
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine: ": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
    "liveServer.settings.NoBrowser": false
}
```

For 32bit system.

```
{
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine: ": "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
    "liveServer.settings.NoBrowser": false
}
```