# Getting 503 status code when index.html tries to load css and scripts [nodejs + express]

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, openshift, http-status-code-503

I'm using static middleware to serve stylesheets and scripts

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Everything works on localhost, but once I deploy the app to openshift I get 503 code for each static file the page tries to load.
If I open another browser tab and directly past the URL of one of those files I actually get the file.

P.S.: I am using express-react-views as a view engine.

Comment: Did you check and verify whether the request url is correct or not using the browser console?.

Comment: Yes, the requested URL is correct, if I open it in another browser tab it correctly gives me back the css file. But the html page is unable to load it since the server response is _503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)_. It's weird, that's why I cannot understand where the issue is.

Comment: Maybe you have put `app.use(app.router);` before `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`? Or your js file is in another folder? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620239/cant-get-index-html-to-show-with-express-in-nodejs?rq=1

Comment: I think I found the problem but I don't know yet how to solve it. I watched the log of the application (deployed in openshift) and I found this error:

Error: EACCES, permission denied '/var/lib/openshift/55ed4f447628e1c8a8000070/.babel.json'

As I said I'm using express-react-views as express engine, and it's using babel to compile JSX back to EC5. It's having issue to access .babel.json. Still, I'm looking on how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I'm using *express-react-views* as a view engine and it includes Babel.js which uses cache for transpilation optimization. The problem is that it tries to write the cache files in a directory that requires higher permission. To solve I disabled the cache.

```
process.env.BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE = 1;
```

I hope this can help other people having the same issue.